# Is there an AutoHotKey for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, autohotkey

I would like to simulate keyboard combinations.

I am able to do this on Windows with AutoHotKey.

Is there an equivalent app for Ubuntu?

Comment: to answer this question correctly: what is the DE (desktop environment, aka 'kde', 'gnome', 'xfce' etc) you are using? if you answer that, one would check out how to bind keys to certain actions.

Comment: I think it's safe to say that Ubuntu implies gnome unless otherwise noted.

Comment: I'm using Gnome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The links in nik's answer are a bit old but still pretty useful, although there have been quite a few advancements since then. There is [**IronAHK**](https://github.com/Paris/IronAHK) currently available which is a complete rewrite of AutoHotkey which works under .NET as well as Mono, allowing it to have cross-platform compatibility. It's also free and fully open source.

Comment: Very promising, but the project doesn't seem to have made any releases yet. I don't see any option other than to fetch and compile the source yourself. Has anyone used it?

Answer (score 5):

Brainstorm Ubuntu: [Idea #588: AutoHotkey for Ubuntu (automation, hotkeys)](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/588/) has some notes.
You may also want to look at [**AutoKey**](http://autokey.sourceforge.net/) - [the (totally rewritten) text expansion and hotkey utility](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1052846).

Finally, this older [Idea #163: Sytem-wide shortcut configuration](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/163/) refers many discussions on the subject. Like `akira` comments, your desktop environment may already support easy key bindings.

Comment: The Brainstorm website has been shut down, and those links don't work any more.

Answer (score 2):

Landed here earlier while searching for one myself.

There is now a **opensource** & **cross platform** alternative.
Robotjs handles mouse, keyboard, and screen(pixels) inputs with js code.

http://robotjs.io/

Example from the website:

```
// Type "Hello World" then press enter.
var robot = require("robotjs");

// Type "Hello World".
robot.typeString("Hello World");

// Press enter.
robot.keyTap("enter");
```

Comment: From FAQ: Q: *Why is <insert key> missing from the keyboard functions?*
A: *We’ve been implementing keys as we need them. Feel free to create an issue or submit a pull request!* Well, that's... peculiar.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to do this with xbindkeys+xvkbd. That is, install xbindkeys, xbindkeys-config, xvkbd. Configure xbindkeys to call xvkbd on Windows keys, i.e. in ~/.xbindkeysrc, add:

```
"sleep 0.2 && /usr/bin/xvkbd -text "\A\t""
    c:115
"sleep 0.2 && /usr/bin/xvkbd -text "\A\t""
    c:116
```

If this works, add xbindkeys to System > Preferences > Sessions > Startup Programs and maybe disable default assignments in ~/.xbindkeysrc

Answer (score 1):

there is a port in progress [ahklinux](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic46546.html)