# hotkey for scrollwheel

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, scroll-wheel

I'm running Ubuntu on a  Thinkpad with a "nipple thingy mouse" and would love to have a way to make super-up and super-down send scrollwheel events. any ideas?

Really I'm looking for a way to convieniently scroll so other ideas are very welcome.

Comment: What is this "nipple thingy mouse" you speak of and where can I get one!?! :-)

Comment: @Josh: http://xkcd.com/243/

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to direct you to this [Autohotkey for Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/44052/is-there-an-autohotkey-for-ubuntu) question. Basically, I and others here could do this in [AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for Windows, and it seems that there are a few growing equivalents in Linux. A fairly simple remapping of a key or key combination to whatever you want.

If you can find how to do this feature, you'll maybe go on to work out how to do everything you've ever wanted to do. That's been my experience with AHK, I hope that the Linux equivalents are up to it. Good luck.

Comment: the autohotkey for ubuntu question doesn't have a working answer. (yet). 
If i interpret your answer loosely you are suggesting creating a key binding that calls a script that sends a mouse event to the current window?

Comment: Yeah sorry. The answers given are in development- IronAHK seems pretty exciting, source code available (if you are happy to work with that.) But yes, the principle is to recognise an input code (nipple down) and replace it with another (scroll down).

Answer (score -1):

- <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> scroll slowly.
- <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> scroll one screen at a time.
- <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> scroll to the start/end of the screen.

Comment: I'm looking for something that will work in any program.

Comment: These _should_ work in any program.

Comment: If the developer chose to handle them correctly.

Comment: Also, Up and Down will work in any program.