# Use trackball to scroll, zoom, etc

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, hotkeys, scrolling, trackball

I've got a Logitech Marble Trackball (which is great, btw).  By setting one of the extra buttons as a "middle" mouse button, when I click it, many apps (like browsers) will start "scrolling mode" so that moving the trackball will scroll up and down.  Most of the time, this is sufficient, but I figure it would be way cooler if I could have several "modes" to do different things like zooming, panning, rotating (particularly in GIMP).  Then when I hold CTRL, CTRL+SHIFT, or some such, it would enter a new mode, and the trackball would behave differently.

I found a couple questions similar to this that suggest using AutoHotKey, but I haven't found an example script to do this, nor can I find out to track mouse movements within AHK.  Any pointers?

[hotkey for scrollwheel](https://superuser.com/questions/65727/hotkey-for-scrollwheel)

[remedy for a no scroll wheel trackball?](https://superuser.com/questions/303661/remedy-for-a-no-scroll-wheel-trackball)

Thanks!

Comment: There are some scripts if you google : autohotkey trackball

Answer (score 5):

After fiddling for quite a while, I came up with this script that works fairly well.  Holding down CapsLock enters into "mouse wheel" mode.  It's also possible to hold CapsLock+Ctrl to get alternate behavior (like zooming), depending on the app.  The script needs to constantly reset the mouse position to keep it on-screen, so it hides the cursor for the duration of the mode (grab the [cursor-hiding script](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/DllCall.htm) as well).

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

*CapsLock:: 
    MouseGetPos, xposinit, yposinit
    xposlast := xposinit
    yposlast := yposinit

    SystemCursor("Off")

    SetTimer, ButtonHold, 10
    KeyWait, CapsLock
    SetTimer, ButtonHold, off

    MouseMove, xposinit, yposinit, 0
    SystemCursor("On")

    Return

    ButtonHold:
        MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos

        if (ypos > yposlast) {
            MouseClick, WheelDown
        } else if (ypos < yposlast) {
            MouseClick, WheelUp
        }

        MouseMove, xposlast, yposlast, 0
```